# How do I keep my /system mounted as read+write all the time?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, root-access, mount, system

I'm running ChainFire3D and for some reason, the per-app setting doesn't seem to work at all. But when I set the default setting itself, it works. I saw that one of ChainFire 3D's requirement is for the /system to be always mounted as read+write. I experimented and by mounting it via Root Explorer and restarted the phone. After restart, /system was back to read only.

So yeah, how do I force it to always be moounted as read+write? This is on CyanogenMod 9, ICS 4.0.4.

Comment: You'd need to alter the `boot.img` and modify the init script within the `boot.img` for this to work. What device are you referring to?

Comment: The device is Xperia ST17i